# On submit form, return false not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

When I submit the form I got an alert message. When I accept the alert it will submit the form anyway. Returning false is ignored. 
Onclick can not be used. I try with `var x = document.forms["form"]["fname"].value;`
and still same.

```
<form id="f" method="post" name="form" onsubmit="return validateForm();" action="#">
    <input type="text" name="fname" id="test" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm() {
            var x = document.getElementById('test').value;
            if (x == null || x == 0 || x == "0") {
                alert("Stop");
                return false;
            }
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: it is working fine, check for any error in your browser console try http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/KJyF8/1

Comment: Working fine here: http://jsfiddle.net/su4jr/

Comment: looks similar to <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3013396/cancel-form-submit-when-showing-alerts>

Comment: There is no error in your form. It is working fine

Comment: Out of curiosity, why has this question been up-voted?

Comment: Unbelievable. It does not work for me : http://jsfiddle.net/L938e/5/ Is this browser issue?? Getting crazy since it seems to be so simple..:)

Comment: There are some issues with IE9 as I see it.

Comment: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0e71njq402 : Seems like wrapping onload in jsfiddle seems to be the issue..:(. But then again, its us who are trying it out with jsfiddle..

Comment: @RoyMJ : this is working at my end and not on jsfiddle :(..why the downvote for answer :(

Comment: @Sonali : I dint downvote.. i just commented it dint work..

Comment: @RoyMJ: yes, i know...:)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of `<input type="submit" value="submit"/>` use `<input type="button" value="Submit" onclick='validateForm()'/>`.

In your JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function validateForm() {
        var x = document.getElementById('test').value;
        if (x == null || x == 0 || x == "0") {
            alert("Stop");
        }
        else
            document.form.submit();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: The question says onclick cannot be used.

Comment: The question would be why not use `onclick` and `onclick` of what.

Comment: Onclick on button is ok. On form is problem because I have 4 buttons.

Comment: @NejcGalof, please ask different questions for different subjects

Answer (score 0):

Give this script inside of head tag and check it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function validateForm() {
            var x = document.getElementById('test').value;
            if (x == null || x == 0 || x == "0") {
                alert("Stop");
                return false;
            }
        }
</script>
```